# Is there any way to get a openbravo developer's copy that I can edit other that using mecurial?

Tags: java, mercurial, openbravo

First of all if this question is somehow related or a duplicate copy of an existing question then I would like to say sorry for that please direct me to the right direction, though I have search within this site and no hits whatsoever...

So my problem is that I like to get and edit openbravo erp system and one way that I've seen it to be possible is to use Mecurial and get a copy with this instruction it say it can take 1 to 2 days to get a copy. Well with my download speed I think it will take 3 to 4 days not sure if it is based on that, when I just want to edit the code as soon as possible. If Im missing something here with the instructions that mecurial is giving like I've said earlier please direct me to the right direction.. I hope to get positive response Thanx for anyone who cares.

lastly sorry for the english if it happens to be unreadable, just ask for clarity thnx....

Answer (score 0):

you can download the latest sources (or any previous version) in a zip file at the following location:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/openbravo/files/02-openbravo-sources/

This is much "lighter" than cloning/downloading our whole repository. However, keep in mind that Openbravo adheres to the modular development approach as opposed to changing the core code directly which is advised against.